# Locked out of Macbook Pro after switching user accounts

Tags: login

I couldn't log on to my corporate macbook pro today after cleaning the keyboard. So I switched user accounts because I had that option.
That showed a logon screen.
but instead of my name being in the user field it is blank. It does not accept any variation of my name or email and my password.

If I restart, I get my corporate logon screen, I am able to logon to that, accept my corporate splash screen , but then instead of taking me to my desktop and old user account, it takes me to the switch user logon screen that I initially had and there is no other option except to shut down or sleep.
What is going on and how can I log back on to my computer?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the OS, what you did to clean the keyboard, what your corporate support did, etc.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Comment: This is sierra osx. pushed keys on keyboard when cleaning keyboard. Unable to contact coporate at this time.